# How to fetch data from oracle database in hourly basis

Tags: sql, database, oracle

i have one table in my database say mytable, which contents request coming from other source. There is one column in this table as Time, which stores date and time(e.g. 2010/07/10 01:21:43) when request was received. Now i want to fetch the data from this table on hourly basis for each day. Means i want count of requests database receive in each hours of a day. e.g.for 1 o'clock to 2 o'clock say count is 50 ..like this.. I will run this query at the end of day. So i will get requests received in a day group by each hour.

Can anybody help me in this.

**I want query which will take less time to fetch the data as my database size is huge.**

Any othre way than OMG Ponies answer.

Comment: What is "huge", how long does the query OMG Ponies offered take, how long do you need it to take.

Comment: Thanks Guys, i got my answer by making some minor changes in OMG Ponies answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [TO_CHAR function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) to format the DATETIME column, so you can GROUP BY it for aggregate functions:

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(t.time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS hourly,
         COUNT(*) AS numPerHour
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(t.time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
```

Comment: i like it, so +1. But can we do it without using join.Because my data is huge.

Comment: @MAS1: Sorry, but I've re-read your question and I don't see anything implying the need for a JOIN.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, i think u use self join in your answer.(t.time)

Comment: @MAS1: No, there's no self join--you'd see the "JOIN"/etc keyword if that were the case.

Comment: @MAS1 that's not a join, it's using the table alias. If you're only looking for data for the current day you can add `WHERE t.time BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) AND TRUNC(sysdate + 1)` between the `FROM` and `GROUP BY` clauses; or you can parameterise that to use a date you pass in.

Comment: @Alex I think you meant (sysdate + 1) there (not + 10)

Comment: @Tony thanks, mis-corrected a typo and made it worse. Fixed it.

Comment: @Alex and @Tony, Will try this also.

Comment: @MAS1: At the risk of stating the obvious, if you don't already have an index on the Time field on your table, you should add one if you can. If the query still takes too long, consider a separate partition on the table for the current day's data.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: The use of TO_CHAR would render the index on the `time` column useless, unfortunately.

Comment: @ Mark Bannister:Thanks for your suggestion of separation of current day's data.

Comment: @OMG: the `WHERE` clause would still use the index to restrict to a single day, and avoid the need to fetch the data blocks for the records that match as well (although I think I read somewhere that `count(*)` could undo some of that and `count(1)` might be more performant - must test that one day).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create another table that stores the count and the date. Create a database job that will run hourly and put the count and sysdate in the new table. Your code will be just querying the new table.

```
create table ohtertable_count (no_of_rows number, time_of_count date);
```

Your database job, that will run hourly will be something like

```
insert into othertable_count 
select count(1), sysdate
from othertable;
```

And you will query the table othertable_count instead of querying your original table.

Comment: .+1,Thanks for your suggestion..but i can't create another table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT To_char(your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS hourly, 
       Count(*)                              AS numPerHour 
FROM   your_table 
WHERE  your_column > '1-DEC-18' 
       AND your_column < '4-DEC-18' 
GROUP  BY To_char(your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') 
ORDER  BY hourly;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get hourly data I am using like below:

```sql
select 
s.req_submit_date,
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM to_timestamp(s.req_submit_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')) hr ,count(*)
from your_table s
where s.req_submit_date >= to_date('20230414', 'yyyymmdd') 
and s.req_submit_date < to_date('20230416', 'yyyymmdd')
group by s.req_submit_date,EXTRACT(HOUR FROM to_timestamp(s.req_submit_date,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
order by s.req_submit_date,hr;
```